# Still faced memory warning after apply ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

After i heard about ARC feature and how it is reduced dealing with memory i have converted my application  which building dynamic forms but still when i make synchronization (Writing huge data on CoreData) from web-service.Is there any guide lines should apply it on application to utilized ARC technology .Our log show that there is a (Received memory warning. Level=1)

Comment: I assume you do asynchronous synchronization using threads. If so, did you wrap your thread with @autoreleasepool{}?

Comment: I have used it when i saving data into CoreData but still the same problem, i want to focused about something that the memory warning level isn't occur when made sync it occur after finished sync and began rotate from landscape to portrait and display number of data in table view

Comment: Did you try to use instruments for leaks detection?

Comment: I have used instruments but there is no leaks but when i tested with memory allocation get may huge allocation

Comment: So probably you do many allocations inside one function without leaving it. Try to split your synchronization process to chunks and synchronize each chunk in a separate function. Otherwise turn off ARC for specific *.m file in build phases to manage memory manually

Comment: If you post your code, we may be able to help you more.  My initial thought is that you probably need a local autorelease pool which gets flushed out on a regular basis during your synchronization, instead of waiting until it is done and returns.

Comment: Ok my code is huge but if i have more iteration and i enclosed all these iteration in on autorelease , are you suggest to separate each iterate with autorelease as once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ARC doesn't magically reduce memory usage - it prevents human error from making memory-consuming mistakes. There is still great importance in understanding reference counting and general memory management in Objective-C even though you're utilizing ARC.

Comment: Ok could you please provide me with advanced ebook specialist in ARC

Comment: Sorry, that's out of my understanding. What I can suggest is running instruments with the new, ARC-enabled project and start eliminating allocations by severity.